# Positioning an element from the bottom left of the element

Tags: javascript, css, position, element

Excuse my terrible MS Paint drawing, but I think it'll be the easiest way for me to explain what I'm trying to ask:
[My ms paint image hosted on imgur because I'm not allowed to include images inline I guess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5OJD.png)

In my code element 1 (listed in the picture) isn't going to move, it's exactly where it needs to be. Element 2 appears when hovering over element 1, kind of like a tooltip. Element 2 is positioned by `absolute`, offset a specific amount of pixels so that it'll appear directly to the top right of element 1.

The issue is that the size of element 2 is going to be different every time you hover over element 1. This makes it impossible to always get element 2 to always appear directly to the top right of element 1, because using `absolute` to position an element sets the "anchor point" to the top left. If element 2 is short, it appears way above element 1. If element 2 is long, its bottom blows way past element 1.

Is there any way to set the "anchor point" of element 2 to its bottom left rather than its top left? I'd prefer to do this in vanilla CSS/JavaScript, but if something like jquery is really necessary then I'll take it. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: A few questions just to clarify. Element 1 is the main element, and element 2 appears when you hover over element 1. So why do you need 3 versions on hover? Example 1 and 2 are more or less the same, but 3 has a space between. If I have a better understanding on why you want it to work that way, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: @Invizi Sorry, I should have explained that better. The first panel and second panel is what I want to occur. No matter the size of element 2, it is positioned directly to the top right of element 1. The final panel is what I don't want to happen. Element 2 happens to be shorter in the third panel, so it appears way above element 2 because it is positioned from the top left most pixel. I want to position it from the bottom left most pixel.

Comment: Is just the height of #2 changing each time? Does its width stay the same?

Comment: @DanZuzevich Yes, the width is constant. Only the height changes.

Comment: I put something together that you can mess around with that should be a good start. Move your mouse in and out of the light gray box, and you should see it gives you what you are looking for. I'm too beat right now to write a long explanation. https://codepen.io/DZuz14/pen/bGRVyYR?editors=1010

Comment: I'm just using a function randomly generate a size for the second box, the size might be the same a few times, so keep that in mind.

Comment: @DanZuzevich Thanks, I'll see what I can pull from this. It would be a lot simpler if elements could just be positioned according to a certain point within the element in css, such as the bottom left point instead of the top left point. I don't get why that wouldn't be a thing by now.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not how it works. It's just a miniscule amount of javascript, I see no problem with using JS.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example I found on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp). I edited it to do what was in your example.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 300px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
  bottom: -50px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  /* Position the tooltip text */
  position: absolute;
  top: -105%;
  left: 105%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```